# Is it possible to track allocation/deallocation?

Tags: c#, memory, hook, allocation

As far as I can tell, this is isn't possible, so I'm really just hoping for a left field undocumented allocation hook function.
I want a way to track allocations like in [_CrtSetAllocHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy8c7wz5.aspx), but for `C#/.NET`.
The only visibility to the garbage collector/allocation appears to be [GC.CollectionCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collectioncount(VS.80).aspx).
Anyone have any other .NET memory mojo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CLR has a 'profiling API' that hooks into pretty much everything - it is what the commercial .NET memory profiling products use, I believe. Here is an MSDN link to the top level of the documentation: [.NET Framework General Reference: About the Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384547.aspx)

See this MSDN magazine article for an introduction to the memory piece: [Inspect and Optimize Your Program's Memory Usage with the .NET Profiler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188781.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use Red Gate's ANTS Profiler. It will tell you a lot about what's going on in memory without you having to learn the profiling API yourself.